# Setting up PAN network on BlueZ stack linux

Tags: pan, bluez

Trying to set up a pan network on my linux machine and need some help !!

1. What all utilities do we need to setup a pan network on a linux machine ?
2. How do you go about assigning an IP to the pan interface on the linux machine?
3. How do we enable telnet/ssh to that interface ?

Can you help me with the basic configuration that might be needed for setting up PAN network on a linux machine ?

My machine is running ubuntu-18.04.

Thanks,
Sandeep